# How to properly type a recursive function in TS?

Tags: typescript, recursion

I need to do a pretty simple task as crawl input arguments and stringify all [Big Numbers](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/) (BN's) if there are any. I want to specify proper types but can't find a way to do that so currently my code looks like that

```
function stringifyBN(value: unknown): unknown {
  if (isBN(value)) {
    return value.toString();
  }

  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map((v) => stringifyBN(v));
  }

  return value;
}
```

`unknown` basically does nothing regarding guarding from errors.

I tried the approach below since my input is either a primitive value or a recursive array of primitive values and it's always an array on the top level.

```
function stringifyBN(
  value: number | string | boolean | BN | number[] | string[] | boolean[] | BN[]
): number | string | boolean | number[] | string[] | boolean[] {
  if (isBN(value)) {
    return value.toString();
  }

  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map((v) => stringifyBN(v));
  }

  return value;
}
```

but got an error

```
Type '(string | number | boolean | string[] | number[] | boolean[])[]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | string[] | number[] | boolean[]'.
  Type '(string | number | boolean | string[] | number[] | boolean[])[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
    Type 'string | number | boolean | string[] | number[] | boolean[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2322
```

Any other approaches don't work neither since I get similar errors and already ran out of ideas. TS should basically help writing code instead creating troubles but I have the second option here.

Could someone help with that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And what is a BN?

Comment: BN = Big number

Comment: It's a Big Number which is software implementation to hold integer number much bigger than JS can. I basically use BN.js but it can be considered as BigInt type in JS. I've updated the description too.

Comment: Can the arrays be mixed? Can an input array contain both booleans and BNs, for example?

Comment: PLease provide several examples of calling this funnction and what return type do you expect

Answer (score 1):

> `unknown` basically does nothing regarding guarding from errors.

`unknown` forces you to have runtime checks on such values, which can already prevent many errors. It is definitely very useful. Do not confuse it with `any` which is the one doing nothing regarding guarding from errors.

Of course it might be possible to get a better type (although in your case I'm not fully convinced that it would be very helpful), but for that we need to know more about the input.

Is it always either a primitive value or an array of similarly types primitive values? Can it be an heterogeneous array? Can it be a tuple? Can it contain deeply nested arrays? Can it contain objects?

**EDIT (answer after clarifications)**

If it can be nested arrays, the type needs to be defined as a recursive type. Here is how you can do it:

```js
// Represents the type of values of type T or potentially nested
// arrays of such values.
type NestedArray<T> = T | NestedArray<T>[];

function stringifyBN(
  value: NestedArray<number | string | boolean | BN>
): NestedArray<number | string | boolean> {
  [...]
}
```

Comment: I've basically defined the input type as `number | string | boolean | BN | number[] | string[] | boolean[] | BN[]`. But the array is actually recursive which means values can be also arrays of primitive values or arrays. The top level call is always an array and then it can be either a primitive or an array.